# 1st July 2022 "Seeing is believing" blog post has a few problems

Tags: bug, blog, podcast, youtube, the-overflow

The blog post [*"Seeing is believing: The Stack Overflow Podcast now available as video"*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/07/01/seeing-is-believing-the-stack-overflow-podcast-now-available-as-video/) has a few problems for me.

1. **There's no clickable link to the [Stack Overflow's YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/c/StackOverflowOfficial).** For example, quoting the blog:

   > Starting today, Stack Overflow will be joining the party, publishing a video version of our weekly podcast **to our YouTube channel** and sharing some highlights and clips on our social media accounts

   I scrolled through the post several times without finding an obvious link I could click to the YouTube channel, or to the episode. (I was left wondering if the podcast has its own YouTube channel or if it's on the SO's main YouTube channel.)
2. At least for me I don't see any video or screenshot of the video in the post, where it says:

   > Below is video to accompany the podcast that was published this morning.

   All I see is a long blank space. (Using Firefox on Windows 10 with everything vanilla.)
3. Apparently there should be another large item at the end of the post but I also can't see it.

Comment: The YouTube videos are embedded; there are two of 'em: One after *Below is video to accompany*, and one at the end.

Comment: @Justin I'm using Firefox with default configs, and I see embedded vids on lots of others sites... If I'm not seeing it I'm making an educated guess other users using default browser settings aren't seeing it either... But even so, there should be a clickable link in the text.

Comment: These are the two embed links: https://www.youtube.com/embed/qnSHI-DGmh4?feature=oembed; https://www.youtube.com/embed/kznjAqTLG9M?feature=oembed

Comment: Empty for me too, Chrome latest. My guess is the default browser settings block embedded video.

Comment: No repro on chrome on android. Perhaps some javascript is being blocked somewhere?

Comment: @Luuklag I don't block anything, no userscripts, no adblocks. Though Chrome did change the default cookies settings not long ago, that's probably the case.

Comment: No repro on chrome (102) PC.

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be triggered by denying targeting cookies. I assume the YouTube embedding includes targeting cookies or by itself counts as targeting as it inevitably submits information to Google.

There should be a proper fallback to the embedding here; failing silently is quite bad UX.

Comment: Not quite, it's a bad UX. Many users are left wondering in front of blank screen space. :/